# rewrite codes which matches a certain ASTMatcher

Tags: clang

I'm new to `clang` and I want to rename member variable name using `ASTMatcher`. For example:

```
class Person
{

public:
    ....

private:
    char m_genger;
         ^^^^^^^^ => rename to gender_

    int m_age;
        ^^^^^^ => rename to age_
};
```

After reading some tutorials now I found how to use `ASTMatcher`, so that I can access location to be modified.

But I got a Seg. Fault right after calling `clang::Rewriter::ReplaceText` or `InsertText`.

### My `ASTMatcher` Program

```
DeclarationMatcher FieldDeclMatcher =
    clang::ast_matchers::fieldDecl().bind("field_decl");

clang::Rewriter rewriter;

class MyMatcher : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback
{
public :
    MyMatcher(clang::Rewriter& rewrite) : m_rewriter(rewrite) {}

    virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result)
    {
        if (const clang::FieldDecl* fs
            = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::FieldDecl>("field_decl"))
        {
            std::cout << "===== found: FieldDecl =====" << std::endl;
            fs->dump();
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // seg. fault occurs here.
            m_rewriter.InsertText(fs->getLocStart(), "/* comment */", true, true);
        }
    }
private:
    clang::Rewriter& m_rewriter;
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
    ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                   OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

    MyMatcher matcher(rewriter);

    clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder finder;
    finder.addMatcher(FieldDeclMatcher, &matcher);

    return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&finder).get());
}
```

### Output of gdb backtrace

```
#0  0x0000000000a52153 in clang::Rewriter::getLocationOffsetAndFileID(clang::SourceLocation, clang::FileID&) const ()
#1  0x0000000000a5516a in clang::Rewriter::InsertText(clang::SourceLocation, llvm::StringRef, bool, bool) ()
#2  0x0000000000422f0d in MyMatcher::run(clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder::MatchResult const&) () at ex03.cc:68
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [Eli Bendersky's post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/07/29/ast-matchers-and-clang-refactoring-tools/), I found the answer.

It seems like that I can't rewrite codes only using `ASTMatcher`, To modify code, we need  not only `ASTFrontendAction` and `ASTConsumer` but `ASTMatcher`.
(please correct me, if I'm wroing)

You can get Eli's code [his github repository](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_clang/matchers_rewriter.cpp).

Comment: Before using the rewriter, one has to set the source manager with setSourceMgr, no need for ASTFrontendAction etc.